# How to write the firebase ServerValue.Timestamp from Xamarin

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin, firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.android

On Xamarin.Android(native)

How to write the timestamp of server on firebase when a key is created or updated.

I found the code on android like below

```
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    System.out.println(dataSnapshot.getValue()); 
}

public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) { }});
ref.setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
```

, but don't found on xamarin.android(native)

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.GetInstance(FirebaseApp.GetInstance(Application.PackageName));

DatabaseReference userRef = database.GetReference("users").Child(userKey);
userRef.SetValue(ServerValue.Timestamp); // build error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ServerValue.Timestamp` is mapped to an `IDictionary` in C# (In Java it is a `Map`).

Cast it to an `Java.Lang.Object` in your `SetValue`:

```
userRef.SetValue((Java.Lang.Object)ServerValue.Timestamp);
```

In your `Firebase.Database.IValueEventListener.OnDataChange` cast the value to a long:

```
var timestamp = (long)snapshot.Value;
```